# Multi-target nuget package does not include runtime files

Tags: nuget-package, .net-standard, csproj

I have a .NETStandard 2.0 class library which is distributed via Nuget. It includes compiled native code libraries, specific to our target platforms. The `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>CoolProject</PackageId>
    <Version>0.8.1</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AnotherCoolProject" Version="0.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="YetAnotherCoolProject" Version="7.4.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x86/native/library32.dll" Update="library32.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/native/library64.dll" Update="library64.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/native/liblibrary.so" Update="liblibrary.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This works great with .NET Core apps on all supported platforms. Lately, though, we discovered issues using this library from .NET Framework apps - the runtime libraries aren't always copied over to referencing projects, leading to `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` exceptions. This appears to be related to this issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1582

As a workaround, we want to add a Framework 4.6.1 target to the package. If I just update the project file above, removing the `TargetFramework` property and adding

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

the project builds without errors, and the nupkg is created with `net461` and `netstandard2.0` folders under `lib/`, but none of the runtime files are included anymore. I can verify this by unzipping the .nupkg, but it's pretty obvious as the package size goes from about 2mb to about 20kb. I've tried adding conditionals to the `ItemGroup` like

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
```

But still nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you got any solution with Multiple frameworks support? I have my library project with < TargetFrameworks > same like you have mentioned above. For me, generated package is working for NetCore2.1 and NetStandard2.0, but it is not working for rest others, NetCore2.0, Net462, Net472. Whereas I do have seperate dependency blocks too.

Comment: We never got it to work, and just target NetStandard 2.0 since that covers all of those frameworks anyway. That ended up being a cleaner solution for us.